# How do I bypass Window's 'Copying'/file transfer window

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am coding a (specific) backup program (for Minecraft) and I would like to know a way I can bypass this window:

[image]

I am still a beginner at Delphi, but I would like to see the different methods I could use to do so.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do the file copy.  If you want it to be silent then include

```
FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR
```

in [`SHFILEOPSTRUCT.fFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).